# Apache Oozie 3.3.2 Build error | Plugin resolution exception

Tags: hadoop, plugins, oozie, build-error, distro

I have been trying to install Oozie with Apache Hadoop version 1.2.1 on Centos 6.4
Maven 3.2.1 has been installed. While trying to build a distribution with the below command, I got the following error

```
mkdistro.sh -e -DskipTests
```

**[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:pom:3.3.2
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin is missing. @ line 742, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 751, column 21**

In {oozie_base_dir}/pom.xml, the above plugin versions were not explicitly declared but mentioned with GroupID & ArtifactID. Also, the specified repository "https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/ext-release-local/" did not contain the above two plugins.

I also referred [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException) for further knowledge.

Explicitly telling versions of plugin in pom file also did not work in my case, as the above mentioned repository no longer had the above two plugins.

Then, I could find the above two plugins in search.maven.org as below, Maven also refers to {home_dir}/.m2/ whenever it could not fetch files from specified repositories.

```
org.codehaus.mojo       http://search.maven.org/#browse|820238317
com.atlassian.maven.plugins   http://search.maven.org/#browse|673055776
```

Request your kind help in guiding me further. Thanks in advance.

And I like to know, why this error has not been so prevalent when I was looking for such kind and every installation method could easily complete mkdistro.sh casually.

Thank you Rajnish, I will go through the link and reg. Java version pls find below.

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the same hadoop version however, with OOZIE 4.0.1 you can refer to the link [rajnishbigdata.wordpress.com/oozie-install](http://rajnishbigdata.wordpress.com/oozie-install/).

Also, do let me know what version of java is installed on your system.

Comment: Dear Rajnish,

Thank you for your input. But, the error is not due to Java version.
As far as I know, its due to missing jars/classes needed for Oozie building - Atlassian & Codehaus as explained above.